# How can QPixmaps get auto-resized in PyQt6 when the Mainwindow is resized?

Tags: qt, qlabel, pyqt6, qmainwindow, qpixmap

I'm playing around with QPixmaps in PyQt.
I want to make them resize while maintaining the same aspect ratio when the window resizes, but when I try, I can only make the window bigger, **never** smaller.

Why is this, and is there a workaround?

Here is the code:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class ResizablePixmapWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, pixmap: QPixmap, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.original_pixmap = pixmap
        self.pixmap_label = QLabel(self)
        self.pixmap_label.setPixmap(self.original_pixmap)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.pixmap_label)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        widget_size = self.size()
        scaled_pixmap = self.original_pixmap.scaled(widget_size, Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.TransformationMode.SmoothTransformation)
        self.pixmap_label.setPixmap(scaled_pixmap)
        self.pixmap_label.resize(scaled_pixmap.size())
        # self.pixmap_label.adjustSize()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Replace 'path_to_image.jpg' with the path of your image file
        pixmap = QPixmap("path_to_image.jpg")
        resizable_pixmap_widget = ResizablePixmapWidget(pixmap, self)

        self.setCentralWidget(resizable_pixmap_widget)
        self.setWindowTitle('Resizable QPixmap')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I've tried to apply the QPixmap to custom QWidget (as seen above) and also a regular Qlablel.

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Replace 'path_to_image.jpg' with the path of your image file
        pixmap = QPixmap("path_to_image.jpg")
        scaled_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.size(), Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.TransformationMode.SmoothTransformation)
        pixmap_label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap_label.setPixmap(scaled_pixmap)

        self.setCentralWidget(pixmap_label)
        self.setWindowTitle('Resizable QPixmap')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I've tried the available aspect ratio modes (KeepAspectRatio, KeepAspectRatioByExpanding & KeepAspectRatio).

In my actual code I gave up and just used a QPushbutton to rezise the QPixmap manually when I resize the window. But this isn't very elegant.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager There is no `setSizeHint()`. But `minimumSizeHint()` could be overridden and return a reasonable minimum size (or even an empty `QSize()`).

Comment: @musicamante Oh, I apologize, I meant size policy, not size hint... It was just a brain fart on my side :) I have deleted the comment it made no sense as I wrote it.

So my suggestion was to change the label's size policy so that it can get smaller than the contained pixmap. But even better solution would be to forget completely about `QLabel` and paint the scaled pixmap in overriden paint event of a plain `QWidget`.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager It seemed strange of you to suggest that :-) Still, the size policy wouldn't suffice, as `minimumSizeHint()` always has precedence: when a pixmap is set, QLabel computes its size hint based on the pixmap (`sizeHint()` and `minimumSizeHint()` are equal for QLabel except when using text with word wrap or HTML), and then it could never have a size smaller than that hint, *unless* the size policy is `Ignored` (discouraged, as it uses an arbitrary reference) or `minimumSizeHint()` is overridden or `setMinimumSize()` is used.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager That said, yes, using a QLabel is usually pointless for this, since the pixmap has to be properly scaled (and we know that `setScaledContents()` ignores the ratio), forcing us to override the `paintEvent()`. Still, in case CPU usage is mandatory, we could take advantage of the C++ side of things, to avoid the python bottlenecks: using the minimum size [hint] as above, we could just update the "shown" pixmap in the `resizeEvent()` and let Qt do all the rest. The benefit of this is that we can also easily set the pixmap alignment just using the related function.

Comment: @musicamante After more thinking about the case... yes you are absolutely right.

Comment: Interesting. I'm going to play with around with qwidget later and see how it goes.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager using a custom QWidget and overriding the paint event did the trick.

Comment: You should however consider also what @musicamante wrote. Doing the scaling may quite expensive operation. So if you want the highest performance, you should do the scaling in **resize event** handler and then cache the scaled pixmap. And in **paint event** handler you just paint the cached scaled pixmap.